# pandasの散布図行列の重複した半分を消したい

Tags: python, pandas

pandasの`pd.scatter_matrix`で作成できる散布図行列の重複した半分を消したいのですが，どうすればよいでしょうか？
コードは以下です．

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv("dataframe.csv")
plt.figure(figsize=(16,16))
pd.scatter_matrix(data)
```

Comment: 「重複した半分を消したい」というのは、グラフとして表示される散布図行列の内、たとえば上三角成分にあたる部分を空白にしたい、ということでしょうか？

Comment: はい，そうです．

Answer (score 0, accepted):

以下のコードで実現できました。具体的には、`scatter_matrix` が subplot たちの numpy array を返していることを利用して、その内の上三角成分のみをイテレートして見えないようにしました。最後の部分では numpy array の上三角行列を作る関数 [`np.triu`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.triu.html) を使っています。(Pandas の `scatter_matrix` のドキュメントが[これ](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/visualization.html#scatter-matrix-plot)しかないようなのであくまでワークアラウンドですが……。)

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3                                                                               

# Numpy 1.13.1、Pandas 0.19.2 です。                                                                 
# Pandas 0.21 では pandas.plotting を import することになると思います。                              

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tools.plotting import scatter_matrix
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, 4), columns = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
subplots = scatter_matrix(df)
mask = np.triu(np.ones(subplots.shape), k = 1).astype('bool')
for plot in subplots[mask]:
  plot.set_visible(False)
plt.show()
```

[image: プロット結果]

なお、行列のサイズが大きくなるようであれば、自前で scatter matrix の各成分を for で計算してサブプロットを作っていく方が、計算を効率良く行えると思います。